# Deserializing Instagram JSON using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, instagram

I'm having a problem deserializing some Json I'm getting from Instagram.

Here's the webclient:

```
var json = client.DownloadString("https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?foursquare_v2_id=4f9e03fce4b0176467266bc1&client_id=****");
```

Which pulls this string:

> {"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"latitude":35.736772,"id":"17812842","longitude":139.339496,"name":"Fresh
>   bagel hoop"}]}

I'm trying to deserialize it into a dynamic object like this:

```
dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Which seems to work, except on the nested array. I can call the root dynamic properties like this:

```
jsonData.meta, or jsonData.data
```

But I cannot get the id like this:

```
jsonData.data.id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, except `data` is an array. You meant `jsonData.data[0].id`.